# Move \item a little bit from left?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I want to move the `item` term a little bit from left? for instance,

[image]

move the first two items  to the right a little bit. How could I do it?

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Consenus \& Distributed}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item[Distributed]  topology
 \item[Consensus]    criterion   
 \end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item One aim, not the same.
\item Consensus filtering is a special case of distributed filtering 
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you might want to spell "consensus" correctly in the heading of the slide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `description` instead of `itemize`

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Consenus \& Distributed}
 \begin{description}[Distributed]   %% [Distributed] is the longest label
 \item[Distributed]  topology
 \item[Consensus]    criterion
 \end{description}
\begin{itemize}
\item One aim, not the same.
\item Consensus filtering is a special case of distributed filtering
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Consenus \& Distributed}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemindent}{1em}
\item[Distributed]  topology
\item[Consensus]    criterion   
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item One aim, not the same.
\item Consensus filtering is a special case of distributed filtering 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```